# Use MySql to decode json data inside a column

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am integrating payment gateway and saving its success or failure response to MySql column.

The data looks like :

```
{"PG_TYPE":"ABCDE","addedon":"2016-10-21 21:44:17","address1":"","address2":"","amount":"54400.00","bank_ref_num":"623911311289","bankcode":"CC"}
```

The data is saving inside column

> success_response

Ho do I Suppose to get PG_TYPE from this column using MySQL query?

P.S. - I am using MySQL version 5.5.52

Comment: Select the column and use `json_decode($column)`  to convert the JSONString to a PHP data structure then pluck the data from the PHP data structure

Comment: Thank for the reply. But I want to do this only using MySql.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think MYSQL 5.5 has the new MYSQL5.7 JSON functionality.

There is a PHP function to convert JSONStrings into PHP data types called `json_decode()`

So

```
SELECT success_response from table where id = 'something'

fetch the row

$response = json_decode($row['success_response']);

echo $response->PG_TYPE;
```